# How to use Model in Javascript (C# MVC ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a .cshtml file in Views, and I am trying to use Model in a script:

```
<script>
    function back()
    {
        var i = 0;
        console.log(@Model[i].Id;)

    }
</script>
```

It sais the name 'i' doesn't exist in the current context.

```
<script>
    function back()
    {
        console.log(@Model[0].Id;)

    }
</script>
```

This works fine. How could I get the i. element of the Model?

Comment: Could you show the model class?

Comment: If you were iterating over the model (for (int i=0; ....), that would be your `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to mix client side and server side code which is really not a good idea, but you can workaround it to make it work by doing like:

```
@{
   int i = 0;
}
<script>
    function back()
    {

        console.log(@Model[i].Id;)

    }
</script>
```

This will work for you, but as i said you shouldn't be doing this kind of things.

Comment: Thanks. But the 'i' cannot be changed in the script if I'm correct, or can it?

Comment: you cannot, what are you actually trying to do, as i said it is not a good idea to mix server and client side code, razor is executed on server side before javascript is executed

Comment: I am trying to make a gallery using script in cshtml. The 'i' stands for the i. image have  to be shown. There's a "Previous image" <td> with an onclick="back()". Function back() should decrease the var i and set an img src to Model[i].NewImage (which is a source of an image).

Comment: you need to use ajax to call server side and return json or partial view

Comment: Could you give me a hint on how to reload partial view with changed parameters, without using ajax? Or is it impossible aswell?

Comment: Could you tell me how should I do it, or where could I learn more about using ajax? I am new to this topic. Thanks for your help.

Comment: a quick google search should give you starting  just search : ajax in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Console.log is javascript so it runs on the frontend, after the page has been rendered so you no longer have access to your MVC Model

You should save your Model to an array on javascript, so it is loaded once the page is redered.

```
function back()
{
    var i = 0;
    var jsArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
    console.log(jsArray[i].Id;)

}
```